# Is it possible to define inline templates in Twig?

Tags: php, twig

I would like to do something similar to this in Twig:

```
{% inlinetemplate input_wrapper %}

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{% block name %}{% endblock name %}">
        {% block label %}{% endblock label %}
    </label>

    <div class="controls">
        {% block controls %}{% endblock controls %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endinlinetemplate %}


{% extendinline input_wrapper %}
{% block label %}Age {% endblock label %}
{% block name %}age{% endblock name %}
{% block controls %}
<select name="age">
    <option ...>...</option>
    ...
</select>
{% endblock controls %}
{% endextendline input_wrapper %}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using [template_from_string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html): `{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}")) }}`?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to clear to me how it would solve the problem.

Comment: What about using [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) instead of extending a template?

Comment: The problem is that I want to pass some more advanced markup as argument to the macros/template. So I want to avoid using 'strings' since it is ugly. If there is a nice way of passing longer strings containing markup and line-breaks to macros, then that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The quick solution

Based on your comments about what you really want, I believe the "block version" of the [set tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) is what you need, i.e.:

```
{% set variableName %}
<p>
    Content block with <i>line-breaks</i>
    and {{ whatever }} else you need.
</p>
{% endset %}
```

Then whatever chunks of markup that you need can be passed to a macro (as others have suggested):

```
{% macro input_wrapper(label, name, controls) %}
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{ name }}">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="controls">{{ controls }}</div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% set label, name = "Age", "age" %}
{% set controls %}
<select name="age">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
{% endset %}

{% import _self as inline %}
{{ inline.input_wrapper(label, name, controls) }}
```

### The real solution

As for the original question, I've done some research and found out that you can **define** inline templates with a combination of the [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) and [verbatim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) tags plus the [template_from_string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) function.

The *content* of the template, however, depends on how you want to **use** it:

1. If you're happy with setting *variables* using the block syntax, use the include [tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) or [function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html).
2. If you need to use *blocks*, as in your original example, you will have to use the [embed](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html) tag.

#### Example using variables and include tag

```
{# Defining the template #}
{% set input_wrapper_string %}
{% verbatim %}
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{ name }}">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="controls">{{ controls }}</div>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
{% endset %}
{% set input_wrapper_tpl = template_from_string(input_wrapper_string) %}

{# Setting the variables #}
{% set label, name = "Age3", "age" %}
{% set controls %}
<select name="age">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
{% endset %}

{# "Rendering" the template #}
{% include input_wrapper_tpl %}
```

#### Example using blocks and embed tag

```
{# Defining the template #}
{% set input_wrapper_string %}
{% verbatim %}
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{% block name %}{% endblock %}">{% block label %}{% endblock %}</label>
    <div class="controls">{% block controls %}{% endblock %}</div>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
{% endset %}
{% set input_wrapper_tpl = template_from_string(input_wrapper_string) %}

{# "Rendering" the template and overriding the blocks #}
{% embed input_wrapper_tpl %}
    {% block label %}Age{% endblock %}
    {% block name  %}age{% endblock %}
    {% block controls %}
    <select name="age">
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

Answer (score -1):

If use Symfony 2 you can use Embedding Controllers (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) or include other template. Also template inheritance can help you to define general blocks.

Comment: I'm not using Symfony 2. Regarding template inheritance, do you have an example of how it could be used to solve my problem?